# Angular show pages for a type of user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-show

I am working on an Angular application, I have two type of users Leader and normal user each one have his own interfaces but there is also common view between the two.
In order to give access to the rightful user to his interfaces I use for now an ng-if (and ng-show/hide if it s just a button in an interface that can only be seen by the leader)
Is it safe to handle this case with this directives or there is another way to do it better? since it is only a bool in the user object that defines whether he is a Leader or a normal user.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc>> ngIf differs from ngShow and ngHide in that ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than changing its visibility via the display css property

So use ng-if more than ng-show and ng-hide or else the user can just change the visibility option using developer tools.

Another approach is using the ng-if in conjunction with ui-router,ui-view directives. This will make the code more modular

```
<div class="commonView">
<!-- leader view -->
    <div class="row" ng-if="isLeader" ui-view="leaderView">

    </div>

<!-- normal view -->
<div class="row" ng-if="!isLEader" ui-view="normalView">

</div>
```